# Load CSV file in single variant column in snowflake table

Tags: csv, variant, snowflake-schema, data-ingestion

Have 100 csv unstructured files and need to load data in single variant column. code posted below will create two rows if two rows are present in the file and requirement is create single row to store data from two rows. what changed I can make in the code?

1. Table will contain data in DATA column

   CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE rtf_lines

   (

   LOADED_AT timestamp,

   FILENAME string,

   FILE_ROW_NUMBER int,

   DATA VARIANT

   );
2. copy data into table and JSON object to support up to 20 CSV columns, it can be extended

COPY INTO rtf_lines

```
from
```

(

```
  SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as LOADED_AT,
    METADATA$FILENAME as FILENAME,
    METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER as FILE_ROW_NUMBER,

    object_construct(
      'col_001', T.$1, 'col_002', T.$2, 'col_003', T.$3, 'col_004', T.$4,
      'col_005', T.$5, 'col_006', T.$6, 'col_007', T.$7, 'col_008', T.$8,
      'col_009', T.$9, 'col_010', T.$10, 'col_011', T.$11, 'col_012', T.$12,
      'col_013', T.$13, 'col_014', T.$14, 'col_015', T.$15, 'col_016', T.$16,
      'col_017', T.$17, 'col_018', T.$18, 'col_019', T.$19, 'col_020', T.$20
    ) as data

  FROM @%rtf_lines T

)

FILE_FORMAT =
```

(

```
  TYPE = JSON

  RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'

  ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE

  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='0x22'

  EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL=FALSE  

);
```

**Code will output as:-**

**Row             1**

LOADED_AT       2022-06-02 06:09:57.363

FILENAME        @RTF_LINES/ui1654167360506/rtf_snowflake_sample.csv

FILE_ROW_NUMBER 1

DATA            { "col_001": "NDTV.com provides latest news", "col_002": " videos from India and the world. Get today’s news headlines from Business", "col_003": " " }

**Row             2**

LOADED_AT       2022-06-02 06:09:57.363

FILENAME        @RTF_LINES/ui1654167360506/rtf_snowflake_sample.csv

FILE_ROW_NUMBER 2

DATA            { "col_001": "Technology", "col_002": " Sports", "col_003": " Movies", "col_004": " videos", "col_005": " photos", "col_006": " live news coverage and exclusive breaking news from India.}

**Output expected as :-**

**Row             1**

LOADED_AT       2022-06-02 06:09:57.363

FILENAME        @RTF_LINES/ui1654167360506/rtf_snowflake_sample.csv

FILE_ROW_NUMBER 1

DATA            { "col_001": "NDTV.com provides latest news", "col_002": " videos from India and the world. Get today’s news headlines from Business", "col_003": " ",
"col_004": "Technology", "col_005": " Sports", "col_006": " Movies", "col_007": " videos", "col_008": " photos", "col_009": " live news coverage and exclusive breaking news from India.}

Comment: Hi - just load the data into a temporary table with one row in the file corresponding to one row in the table and then use standard SQL to sort the data out in the way you want and write it to the final table

Comment: @NickW can you help me with the command?

Comment: @NickW solution worked for me..I used listagg function with groupby clause then I can see one row for one file